# How frequently is Personalized Prediction Data updated?

Tags: support, personal-data

I downloaded the JSON file located at https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data and noticed at the bottom it mentioned when it was generated:

```
  "GeneratedOn": "2018-03-14",
```

Today is the 14 March 2018 so can I take it this is updated every day, if not how often is it updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is updated every day at around about 0:00 GMT